# Select list ajax callback fire only once to update textfield

Tags: forms

I face an issue when fire ajax callback function in my coding. I have a select list and a text box. If there is any change in select list field, the text box will be updated by selected value. I added my code in form_alter function. But, it fired only one time. Below is my code.

```
 function field_collection_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if($form_id == 'employee_performance_node_form') {

$form['field_my_weight_select'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#ajax']= array(
      'callback' => 'custom_test_entity_callback',
      'wrapper' =>'custom_test_entity_wrapper',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
      'event' => 'change',
    );

$form['field_text_for_test']['#prefix']='<div id="custom_test_entity_wrapper">';  
$form['field_text_for_test']['#suffix']='</div>';


if(isset($form_state['values']['field_my_weight_select'])){     
      $content_type = $form_state['values']['field_my_weight_select'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
      $form["field_text_for_test"][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#value']=$content_type;
    }
    else{ $form["field_text_for_test"][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#value']=1;}
}
}

function custom_test_entity_callback($form, $form_state){
  return $form['field_text_for_test'];
}
```

Could you tell me what is wrong in my code??

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue has been solved. I gave the normal user full permissions and I disable the permissions one by one until I found that the permissions that related to Pathauto module cause this issue. So, I enable them and then my code works.

Answer (score 0):

Quickly tested your code and it works.

The only thing that looks a bit odd in your hook implementation, is the name of the function. It seems you are writing your custom code as if your module was named 'field_collection'. There is already a contrib module called that, and you may have already installed it. It would be better to place your function into your custom module's "namespace". Event better would be to also use the [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) hook, since it's more efficient.

In any case, with those two small rewrites, the code ran as expected and I was able to get multiple ajax updates of the text_for_test field.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function YOUR_CUSTOM_MODULE_form_employee_performance_node_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['field_my_weight_select'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#ajax'] = array(
    'callback' => 'custom_test_entity_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'custom_test_entity_wrapper',
    'method' => 'replace',
    'effect' => 'fade',
    'event' => 'change',
  );

  $form['field_text_for_test']['#prefix'] = '<div id="custom_test_entity_wrapper">';
  $form['field_text_for_test']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

  if (isset($form_state['values']['field_my_weight_select'])) {
    $content_type = $form_state['values']['field_my_weight_select'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    $form["field_text_for_test"][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#value'] = $content_type;
  }
  else {
    $form["field_text_for_test"][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#value'] = 1;
  }
}

/**
 * Ajax callback for updating field_text_for_test.
 */
function custom_test_entity_callback($form, $form_state) {
  $form['field_text_for_test']['#prefix'] = '<div id="custom_test_entity_wrapper">';
  $form['field_text_for_test']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
  return $form['field_text_for_test'];
}
```

Update: If you want to make sure, your form alter hook is called last (in relation to other modules):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_module_implements_alter().
 */
function CUSTOM_MODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook != 'form_employee_performance_node_form_alter') {
    return;
  }
  $module = 'CUSTOM_MODULE';
  $group = array($module => $implementations[$module]);
  unset($implementations[$module]);

  $implementations = $group + $implementations; //You want your implementation to run last.
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: But actually I am trying to alter the filed_collection module and this why I use  field_collection_form_alter.

Comment: The convention is that such a MYMODULE_hook implementation belongs to MYMODULE code/files. This is where it is also expected to be found (by developers at least). This is not really blocking you from altering the field_collection module's form elements. A form alter hook is in any case not a field_collection specific thing, but a Form API one.

Comment: I do not know if I understand your idea or not. But could I add the above code in field_collection_form_alter or not?

Comment: You should not have a function field_collection_form_alter at all, it means you are messing with a contrib module's code. Unless you are creating a patch for the module (which does not seem to be the case), this is a bad practice and idea. You should instead create you own module, e.g. performance_customizations, and inside that module's performance_customizations.module file, you should place the form alter hook which would then be named performance_customizations_form_employee_performance_node_form_alter

Comment: Ok, I understand now.. But I could not do custom module now because I already did a lot of customization and alter in field_collection_form_alter. So, do you have a way to let this code work in field_collection_form_alter?? Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see any problem with the code you posted. If there are other parts of code that may be causing the error, you should post them as well in the original question. And you can always try to run that part of the code in a separate module and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: The other parts of the code is just hide and dispaly the fields in field collection.. I do not think it causes this error.. I will try to run this code in separate module and I will check.. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to disable all the other parts of the code but the isuue is still. I notice that the id of textfield is change after the first selection

Comment: before <div id="custom_test_entity_wrapper"><div class="field-type-text-form field-name-field-text-for-test-form field-widget-text-textfield form-wrapper" id="edit-field-text-for-test"><div id="field-text-for-test-add-more-wrapper"><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-text-for-test-und-0-value">
  <label for="edit-field-text-for-test-und-0-value">Text for test </label>
 <input class="text-full form-text" type="text" id="edit-field-text-for-test-und-0-value" name="field_text_for_test[und][0][value]" value="1" size="60" maxlength="255">
</div>
</div></div></div>

Comment: after <div class="field-type-text-form field-name-field-text-for-test-form field-widget-text-textfield form-wrapper" id="edit-field-text-for-test--2"><div id="field-text-for-test-add-more-wrapper--2"><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-text-for-test-und-0-value">
  <label for="edit-field-text-for-test-und-0-value--2">Text for test </label>
 <input class="text-full form-text" type="text" id="edit-field-text-for-test-und-0-value--2" name="field_text_for_test[und][0][value]" value="4" size="60" maxlength="255">
</div>
</div></div>

Comment: Okay, you found the reason why it doesn't works the second time. I updated my code update (custom_test_entity_callback), in order to force the #id to be returned via AJAX. Could you try it like this and check if the updated HTML contains the <div id="custom_test_entity_wrapper"> wrapper?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. In the second time it contains <div id="custom_test_entity_wrapper"> but the id of the input change  <input class="text-full form-text" type="text" id="edit-field-text-for-test-und-0-value--2" name="field_text_for_test[und][0][value]" value="4" size="60" maxlength="255">  (--2) was added to the id. I don't know why..

Comment: Could anyone help me to find a solution to this issue?

Comment: You need to update your post with more information. Your current drupal version as well as the contrib modules you are using. And any additional custom code that you think may be related. From your side, you should try to disable contrib modules and/code gradually, in order to find out which is actually causing the problem. The code you posted afaict is correct and it worked on my standard D7.53 without any problems.

Comment: I create a custom module and it my code works. What I discover today that my code is working in an admin user account but it does not work in a normal user. Before, I just test it in a normal user account. I tried to check the permissions but I did not find any permission that related to ajax. So, do you have an idea why it does not work in a normal user account?  Thank you

Comment: This piece of code, does not have any roles-specific logic. That means, that it should work the same for all kind of roles. Unless there is some other module changing things. Which one cannot tell from the code you provide, unfortunately.

Comment: You can try (a) changing the module hook order (see code update in my answer. If that doesn't work, you should (b) debug this using a proper debugger and backtracing to locate the code that changes the form array. Or, start disabling contrib modules till you figure out which one introduces the conflict. Tedious, I know, go for the proper debugging if you have the option.

Comment: Thank you Stefanos Petrakis for your help and for you support. I found who causes this issue. I gave the normal user a full permissions and I tried to disable permissions one by one. Then, I found that the permissions of Pathauto module causes this issue. So, I enable the permissions and my code is working now.

Comment: Excellent. Best thing to do now would be to give a separate answer to this question for other people to find, describing your findings.